# Stop reading from fgets if there are too many characters

Tags: c

So i have a char array and using fgets I store the string into my fgets. I want to stop reading and prompt the user to enter the string again with less characters. I do not want the string that was too long to be stored but just to be forgotten.

```
char questionLength[50];
  printf("Second can you tell me the question for your answer\n");
  fgets(questionLength, 50, stdin);
```

so more than 50 characters are entered, a prompt to ask the user to reenter the string which is then stored if its less than or equal to 50 characters.

Comment: `questionLength` looks like a troublesome name for an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the last character is a newline in `questionLength` (`fgets()` will read in the newline if there's room). If so, you know it's less than or equal to 50 chars.
Otherwise, the input is longer.

When the input is *exactly* 49 bytes then there won't be a newline. You can work around it by reading one more character (change `questionLength` size of 51).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the last character was a newline. If it was, the input is good (you may want to remove the newline), otherwise read all available chars up to and including the next newline (minding read errors,  eof) and repeat.

```
char questionLength[50];
tryagain:
printf("Second can you tell me the question for your answer\n");
fgets(questionLength, 50, stdin);
size_t len = strlen(questionLength);
if (questionLength[len - 1] != '\n') {
    int ch;
    do ch = getchar(); while (ch != '\n'); /* error checking ommited */
    goto tryagain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll know if the whole string was read because it contains a `newline`. If you want to discard the remainder of any long string, an easy way is to read it all in the first place. If it was read in a single attempt, that's good.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRLEN 50

int main(void) 
{
    char questionLength[STRLEN+2];          // 1 for newline, 1 for EOS
    int tries;

    while(1) {
        tries = 0;
        printf("Second can you tell me the question for your answer\n");
        do {
            if(fgets(questionLength, sizeof questionLength, stdin) == NULL) {
                exit(1);
            }
            tries++;
        } while(strchr(questionLength, '\n') == NULL);

        if(tries == 1) {
            printf("You entered: %s", questionLength);
        }
        else {
            printf("Your entry was too long\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```